# How to use DebugSession.customRequest to run an arbitrary gdb command and get results

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode debug APIs from an extension. My goal is to read CPU registers for a C++ program from a gdb/lldb debugger during a debug session. I also have similar requests for other things (reading memory, disassembly, etc.) that current debuggers don't provide

I have the following in my extension...I can provide a full test case if needed. Yes, I know I have a bug here in that after the first await, the session may not be active anymore and I don't have full error checking shown.

```js
static async getRegisters() {
    const session = vscode.debug.activeDebugSession;
    if (session && text) {      // Make sure we still have a session
        // The following gets me the right result
        const sTrace = await session.customRequest('stackTrace', { threadId: 1 });
        const frameId = sTrace.stackFrames[0].id; 

        // The following does execute but the results are printed to debug console
        // rather than returning the result
        // I tried many variations of arguments and contexts types
        const text = '-exec -data-list-register-names';
        const arg : DebugProtocol.EvaluateArguments = {expression: text, frameId: frameId, context:'hover'};
        session.customRequest('evaluate', arg).then((response) => {
            console.log(response.result); 
        });
    }
}
```

I want the results of gdb somehow provided back to my extension. The results are being printed to the Debug Console instead and I get an empty string. I have also tried setting up an event handler `vscode.debug.onDidReceiveDebugSessionCustomEvent` for custom commands but nothing fires. Is there a better way?

Maybe the first argument to `customRequest` should not be `'evaluate'` but I don't see anything else in the [DebugProtocol spec.](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification) to send a custom command to the actual debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same issue! Here is my solution:

1. Register a "DebugAdapterTracker" (I believe you already know about it);
2. In "onDidSendMessage(message: any)" of the tracker, be aware of the "event" messages, especially when "message.event === "output"";
3. Check the "message.body.output", surprise!

It seems instead of a response with proper values, the DA directly triggers an event to print on the debug console.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `context: 'repl'` if you want to use the result from `.then`

The resopnse object will actually be of type [`EvaluateResponse.body`](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Evaluate) if evaluation was successful. [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5a175207de7c6d0821b3318cfdbe73bb9448ed57/src/vs/workbench/api/browser/mainThreadDebugService.ts#L251)

```js
const args = {
  expression: text,
  frameId: frameId,
  context: 'repl'
};
session.customRequest('evaluate', args).then(({result}) => {
  console.log(result); 
});
```